# problems with $().click() when generating JavaScript code with a PHP loop

Tags: php, javascript

Regards. 
I am generating an .click event for every element of my table using a php loop like this:

```
<?php foreach ($elements as $element){ ?>
    var element_id = <?= json_encode($element['element_id']));?>;

    $('#'+element_id+'_button').click(function() {
        $('#'+element_id+'_interval').toggle();
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
        else{
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
    <?php }?>
```

the problem is, when `$('#'+element_id+'_interval').toggle();` the element is not responding but it adds and removes the classes correctly, somebody help me please.

Comment: Woooo dude!! Mixing php with Javascript? That's new!! :D You can NOT do that!

Comment: @Steve of course you can.

Comment: PHP really has nothing to do with this. Post the rendered HTML please.

Comment: Not in the way he is trying to so so, unless he is trying to generate a .JS file on the fly...

Comment: Sure you can, but you'd be much much wiser to add a class to each button element and delegate an more general click event.

Comment: @steve When did CSS come into the picture?

Comment: @Cecchi sorry, i mean JS :)

Comment: @steve, yes you can use php to generate a html page which comtains the javascript that will be run once rendered. I see your confusion though. :)  I use this method for complex google maps javascript.

Comment: Other way could be something like: 
`var array_elements = <?= json_encode($elements);?>
$(array_eleements).each(function(){
 $('#'+this.element_id+'_button').click(function() {
        $('#'+this.element_id+'_interval').toggle();
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
        else{
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });`

but is exactly the same thing, is something else going on in here I think

Comment: @karmafunk oh, i see what you mean... ok. My mistake :)

Comment: @Ray_Poly I think the problem is not in the code you shared, Are you sure about that you have that element in your page? Have you checked DOM?

Comment: what I don't understand is why .click works for every element and not .toggle, there must be something going on with element_id

Answer (score 3):

Use a class, makes your code a lot cleaner, however if you have to do it this way you should know that your element_id variable is constantly being rewritten.

Try something like:

```
<button class="toggler" data-target="#interval_1"></button>

$(".toggler").click(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).data("target"); // would return #interval_1
    $(target).toggle();

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to firstly separate your php from your javascript.
Otherwise (between other) it will be difficult to maintain.

As a start, you could do the loop with javascript

Comment: I have 352 elements so far and is going to get bigger, I need to do this with a php loop.

Comment: Actually you should not need to loop at all, look at @cernunnos answer

Answer (score 0):

Put the binding events into a seperate method, and call the method in your document.ready script:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      bindBtns();
});

function bindBtns()
{
    <?php foreach ($elements as $element){ ?>
    var element_id = <?= json_encode($element['element_id']));?>;

    $('#'+element_id+'_button').click(function() {
        $('#'+element_id+'_interval').toggle();
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
        else{
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
     });
     <?php }?>
}
```

Comment: I have my loop in .ready() is working fine, .click executes for every element separately but is not toggling if that is a word

Comment: Can you post the html output of 2-3 buttons including the objects you are looking to toggle